# Display powerapps instead of display pane

Tags: document-set, powerapps-forms

Can I completely skip the property pane and show directly the powerapps form on the right hand pane?

I know I can disable quick edit from the advanced settings of the document library, but this is still an extra step to click on edit all

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a standard behaviour for SharePoint Libraries. In order to get to your Power App form, you need to 1) click on on the little information circle and 2) the click on the "Edit all" link:

[image]

Now you will see a "Hidden" Power App form:

[image]

**Update**

If you want to directy open the Power App form, you can do this:

- Create a new column. Make sure it always has data in it.
- Format this column with JSON formatting and use this code. Update the URLs accordingly.

```
{
    "elmType": "a",
    "txtContent": "",
    "attributes": {
        "target": "_blank",
        "iconName": "OpenInNewWindow",
        "class": "sp-field-quickAction",
        "href": {
            "operator": "+",
            "operands": [
                "https://TENANT.sharepoint.com/sites/ModernTeamSiteA/Shared%20Documents/Forms/EditForm.aspx?ID=","[$ID]",
                "&Source=https://TENANT.sharepoint.com/sites/ModernTeamSiteA/Shared%20Documents",
                "@currentField"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks! sorry, I did update the question, but still will accept your answer

Comment: Thank you. Updated the answer with an option for you.